# Wrong #/Types of Arguments in Parameterized For Loop Cursor

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I am trying to display a cursor by feeding it into temporary table and using dynamic sql.

My issue lies in calling the actual cursor in the for loop. I've tried just doing a basic open, and that doesn't work either.

I double checked that everything being called has the same datatypes and am inserting the same # of items as exist in the cursor definition.

```
SQL> -- /* Given a CallNum
SQL> -- Loop through table waiting and grab all records where pCallnum = callnum
SQL> -- Assign a rank sorted by requested time */
SQL> 
SQL> describe students;
 Name                                                                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SNUM                                                                                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)
 SNAME                                                                                                                      VARCHAR2(10)
 STANDING                                                                                                                   NUMBER(1)
 MAJOR                                                                                                                      VARCHAR2(3)
 GPA                                                                                                                        NUMBER(2,1)
 MAJOR_GPA                                                                                                                  NUMBER(2,1)

SQL> describe waiting;
 Name                                                                                                              Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SNUM                                                                                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(3)
 CALLNUM                                                                                                           NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 REQUESTEDTIME                                                                                                              DATE

SQL> 
SQL> select * from students;

SNU SNAME        STANDING MAJ        GPA  MAJOR_GPA                                                                                                                                                     
--- ---------- ---------- --- ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                                     
101 Andy                3 IS         2.8        3.2                                                                                                                                                     
102 Betty               2            3.2                                                                                                                                                                
103 Cindy               3 IS         2.5        3.5                                                                                                                                                     
104 David               2 FIN        3.3          3                                                                                                                                                     
105 Ellen               1            2.8                                                                                                                                                                
106 Frank               3 MKT          3          2                                                                                                                                                     
107 John                2 IS           4        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
108 Jacob               1 MKT        3.6        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
109 Heimer              3 MKT        3.1        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
110 Smith               3 IS         3.1        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
111 Jaden               2 MKT          2          1                                                                                                                                                     

SNU SNAME        STANDING MAJ        GPA  MAJOR_GPA                                                                                                                                                     
--- ---------- ---------- --- ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                                     
112 Will                3 MKT        3.7        2.1                                                                                                                                                     
113 Ethan               2 MKT        3.5        3.1                                                                                                                                                     
114 Julia               1 MKT        3.8        3.5                                                                                                                                                     
115 Revy                1 IS         2.5        1.6                                                                                                                                                     
116 Goku                1 MKT        3.7        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
117 Ken                 3            3.1                                                                                                                                                                
118 Natsu               2            3.1                                                                                                                                                                
119 Gerry               2 IS         3.1        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
120 Terry               2 MKT        3.1        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
121 Dee                 3 MKT        3.1        2.9                                                                                                                                                     
SQL> select * from waiting;

SNU    CALLNUM REQUESTED                                                                                                                                                                                
--- ---------- ---------                                                                                                                                                                                
113      10165 05-AUG-13                                                                                                                                                                                
114      10165 06-AUG-13                                                                                                                                                                                
115      10165 07-AUG-13                                                                                                                                                                                
115      10110 07-AUG-13                                                                                                                                                                                
SQL> 
SQL> Create or replace procedure p_Get_Waiting (
  2          p_CallNum number) as
  3  
  4          CURSOR c_Get_Waiting (p_CallNum number)
  5          IS
  6              select
  7              waiting.snum as snum,
  8              sname,
  9              callnum,
 10              requestedtime
 11              from waiting, students
 12              where callnum= p_CallNum and waiting.snum = students.snum;
 13  begin
 14  
 15          -- Create temporary table
 16          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table waitlistquery (
 17              snum varchar2(3),
 18              sname varchar2(10),
 19              callnum number(5),
 20              requestedtime date)';
 21  
 22          -- For every student in cursor, insert record into temp table
 23          for eachstudent in c_Get_Waiting
 24          LOOP
 25              insert into waitlistquery values (eachstudent.snum, eachstudent.sname, eachstudent.callnum, eachstudent.requestedtime);
 26          end loop;
 27  
 28          -- Display contents of temp table
 29          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
 30              'select RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY callnum ORDER BY requestedtime) as Rank,
 31              snum,
 32              sname,
 33              callnum,
 34              to_char(requestedtime, ''mm/dd/yyyy hh12am'') as RequestedTime
 35              from waitlistquery';
 36  
 37          -- Drop temp table
 38          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table waitlistquery';
 39  
 40  end;
 41  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P_GET_WAITING:

LINE/COL ERROR                                                                                                                                                                                          
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                              
23/2     PL/SQL: Statement ignored                                                                                                                                                                      
23/21    PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to                                                                                                                                       
         'C_GET_WAITING'
```

My goal is to display the results like this:

```
Ranking SNUM SName RequestedTime
--------------------------------
1       107  John  1/1/2010 10am
2       108  Jake  1/2/2012 12pm
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare the variable for each column   as you cant use a `tablename%ROWTYPE`
for eachstudent  since its a join of two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. When you open the cursor, you need to pass the parameters in, e.g. `for eachstudent in c_Get_Waiting(p_CallNum => p_CallNum)`
2. If you're dynamically creating the waitlistquery table as part of the procedure, the insert statement also needs to be dynamic, not static as you currently have. (The procedure compilation will fail, due to the waitlistquery table not existing.)
3. Your `execute immediate select rank()...` statement won't do anything, since you haven't specified any variables for the results of the statement to be stored.

On the second and third points, I assume that this is just a learning exercise? Because if not, there is no point in doing what you're doing; you could simply open a ref cursor to do the job.

If I was doing this, I'd write a function that returned a ref cursor, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_waiting(p_callnum NUMBER) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  get_waiting_rcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN get_waiting_rcur FOR
    SELECT rank() over(PARTITION BY callnum ORDER BY requestedtime) AS rank,
         waiting.snum,
         sname,
         callnum,
         to_char(requestedtime, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh12am') AS requestedtime
    FROM   waiting
    INNER  JOIN students
    ON     waiting.snum = students.snum;

  RETURN get_waiting_rcur;
END f_get_waiting;
/
```

remembering that the code calling this function needs to handle the closing of the cursor once it's done its thing.

This assumes that the data is going to be passed outside of the database (e.g. passed to a C# calling module, written out to a file, etc); if you're going to use the data to do something like inserting into or updating a table, I'd try and do the work in a single DML statement, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Once you simplify your procedure with a cursor with single statement using proper joins, you may display the output  using a `REFCURSOR` bind variable and SQL* Plus print command.

**Modified Procedure**

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE p_get_waiting (
     p_callnum NUMBER,
     c_get_waiting OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
BEGIN
 OPEN c_get_waiting FOR
   SELECT RANK() OVER(
     PARTITION BY w.callnum
     ORDER BY requestedtime
   ) AS rank,
       s.snum,
       s.sname,
       w.callnum,
       TO_CHAR(w.requestedtime,'mm/dd/yyyy hh12am') AS requestedtime
  FROM waiting w
  JOIN students s ON w.snum = s.snum
 WHERE w.callnum = p_callnum;

END;
/
```

**Execution**

```
VARIABLE get_waiting REFCURSOR
EXEC p_get_waiting ( 10165,:get_waiting)

PRINT get_waiting
```

**Result**

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.



      RANK       SNUM SNAME     CALLNUM REQUESTEDTIME  
---------- ---------- ------ ---------- ---------------
         1        113 Ethan       10165 08/05/2013 12AM
         2        114 Julia       10165 08/06/2013 12AM
         3        115 Revy        10165 08/07/2013 12AM
```